# Set up certs for multiple domains in Postfix and Dovecot

Tags: postfix, ssl-certificate, email-server, dovecot

I don't know how to set up main.conf postfix config file and 10-ssl.conf dovecot config files in order to make my mail server capable to handle with multiple certificates. Let me explain... I have two domains at the same server, say

- `mail.example.it`
- `mail.example.com`

and two different certificates for both in different folders

- `etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.it`
- `etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com`

The question is how should I set the tls parameters on main.conf of postfix configuration? It seems to support only one entry on

- `smtpd_tls_cert_file`
- `smtpd_tls_key_file`

The same issue on 10-ssl.conf of dovecot configuration: seems to support only one entry for

- `ssl_cert`
- `ssl_key`

Many thanks for help

Answer (score 11):

This is done by looking at the unencrypted domain name in the [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) header in the TLS handshake to select the right certificate before any encrypted data is exchanged. At the moment (I'll edit this answer if this changes)

Update : SNI support introduced in postfix 3.4.0 - http://www.postfix.org/announcements/postfix-3.4.0.html

Dovecot, on the other hand, does. See this example configuration:

```
# Default
ssl_cert = </path/to/default/cert
ssl_key = </path/to/default/private/key

# mail.example.it
local_name mail.example.it {
    ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.it
    ssl_key = </path/to/mail.example.it/private/key
}

# mail.example.com
local_name mail.example.com {
    ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com
    ssl_key = </path/to/mail.example.com/private/key
}
```

You can leave out each domain's `ssl_key` if it's the same as the default.

Comment: For Dovecot, the example configuration comes from https://wiki.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration#With_client_TLS_SNI_.28Server_Name_Indication.29_support

Comment: should be the accepter answer (if your version match)

Answer (score 7):

To my knowledge, this is not possible. You have two options:

- Use one domain as the MX for all your other domains that the server should handle. So, if you have a cert configured for `example.com` and you want also handle mails for `example.org`, set an MX entry pointing to your `example.com` server into the `example.org` zone.
- Use certs with multiple SANs for every domain you need. This means you have only one cert file that covers all your domains.

Comment: New to me: Let's Encrypt now supports SAN mechanism! Otherwise, in case these two domains were from separate customers that wouldn't want their domains to be used for others, I'd have suggested adding a third domain from the service provider as the certificate domain for both.

Comment: What I couldn't find: does Let's Encrypt have a limit for max SAN host names? Using fixed service provider domain would be a better choice with many customer domains if there was such a limit, or if the changes to this domain name list were frequent.

Comment: @EsaJokinen: It's 100 names. `f you have a lot of subdomains, you may want to combine them into a single certificate, up to a limit of 100 Names per Certificate. ` https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/   I am not sure, but I believe this is the general limit on SANs in TLS certs.

Comment: So, not really a problem, because updating the domain list would get to the nerves long before the limit. :)

Comment: Been using LE with the limit of 100 domain names per certificate for a decade, and very happy with it. At first there were some user comments claiming privacy issues, but now even the opposite is happening, people are glad their SSL/TLS certs are valid for a range of names, since they're all valid, non-spam, non-malware, non-corporate, reliable, domain names, which in a way makes the cert for mail usage more reputable too. So, I'd say, if at all possible, use wildcard domain certs and add 100 to one cert. All other config options end up not being worth the hassle. (And yes, I've tried both.)

Answer (score 3):

Postfix 3.4 and later now allows SNI maps to deal with multiple certificates for different domains/subdomains:

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#tls_server_sni_maps

Hints about configuring it properly with Let's Encrypt:

http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/How-to-use-the-new-server-TLS-SNI-feature-3-4-x-td100786.html#a100819

In summary, here is what user [@MK](http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=user_nodes&user=6775) of the Postfix mailing list says (in case the above link goes down for some reason):

```
----- main.cf -----
# provide the primary certificate for the server, to be used for outgoing connections
smtpd_tls_chain_files =
 /etc/letsencrypt/live/servername.serverdom.com/privkey.pem,
 /etc/letsencrypt/live/servername.serverdom.com/fullchain.pem

# provide the map to be used when SNI support is enabled
tls_server_sni_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map
-----
```

```
----- /etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map -----
# Compile with postmap -F hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map when updating
# One host per line
servername.serverdom.com 
 /etc/letsencrypt/live/servername.serverdom.com/privkey.pem 
 /etc/letsencrypt/live/servername.serverdom.com/fullchain.pem
servername.otherdom.com 
 /etc/letsencrypt/live/servername.otherdom.com/privkey.pem 
 /etc/letsencrypt/live/servername.otherdom.com/fullchain.pem
-----
```

Then run

`$ postmap -F hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map`

Restart `postfix` as normal.

Run

`$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:25 -servername servername.otherdom.com -starttls smtp`

`$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:25 -servername servername.serverdom.com -starttls smtp`

To test: you'll find the hostname under the certificate details. It will match the default server name of the host if there is not a match. Be sure the server name of the host is in the map file for that reason.

**Note:** I haven't tested this out myself, I was just looking for some hints on *how* to do it, and by chance came across this SF thread...

Answer (score 0):

While @Billy gave the solution for `Dovecot` — which works for me, these two posts helped me a lot with `Postfix`: [Postfix and multiple SSL certificates](https://lxadm.com/Postfix_and_multiple_SSL_certificates), and [Using multiple “myhostname” in postfix](https://serverfault.com/questions/624373/using-multiple-myhostname-in-postfix).

Comment: This, of course, requires multiple IP addresses.

Comment: Would it work if I used virtual IP addresses internally?