# Dynamically associate myhostname in postfix

Tags: postfix

A server has multiple domains, each having its respective `return-path` and `from` (identical for each domain): `confirmation@domain1.tld` and `confirmation@domain2.tld`

While this [detailed answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/624373/using-multiple-myhostname-in-postfix) provides useful paths for different versions of postfix, I wonder if there is not a simpler solution, as
each domain happens to point to the same mail server.

Can it not be devised to take the domain of the sender and use `mail.domain.tld` for `myhostname`.

Comment: But why? Doesn't offer any advantage to have multiple myhostname's. All domains can use the myhostname.

Comment: right, but the email header then shows the value of myhostname in the line `Received: from www.someother.ws` and that could be a spam flag...

Comment: Nope, why would be a spam flag ? As long that IP is allowed to send mail for the domain ( SPF etc ), the hostname translates to the IP, and maybe reverse IP points back to hostname, everything should be ok.

Comment: That's not a spam flag at all. Trying to fake it, as you are proposing, is a spam flag.

Comment: @MichaelHampton . That is an interesting observation. if both domains are allowed to send mail, then it is not faking it.  My worry is that different domains with different users have different activity and thus the single myhostname *could* be affected negatively.

Comment: The problem there isn't so much the hostname as the IP address. If you really want to separate domains' reputation, you'll need to keep them on separate IP addresses.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  Point well taken.